# JAX-WS Service Life Cycle

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am developing a JAX-WS webservice which get services from another server. I have to open socket and close socket to use this service.

I am looking for some method in which i could open socket at deployment and close socket on un deployment of webservices.

I planned to use @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy but it doesnt fullfill my requirement

@PostConstruct is only called when a new instance is added to the Method-ready pool

@PreDestroy is only called when the application server decides to reduce the size of the Method-Ready pool - i.e. it determines it doesn't need to keep as many instances of your @WebService.

Please recommend how i resolve this. i tried to open and close socket at every request but it results in timeout at client end.

Regards,
Imran

Answer (score 0):

You could check in the Constructor or in the PostConstruct annotated method that your static Socket whether is initialised (non null for instance). And initialised it if needed.

You can if you need maintain a static int with the number of instance loaded.

You could then use either in Finalize or PreDestroy decrease the counter and destroy the socket if it reaches 0.